# mysql manual increment ids?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table with items in it (id, name, etc) and I want some kind of database scheme to be able to have multiple copies of the item while still being able to increment the ids. There will be a field called startdate or date_from_which_this_entry_should_be_used.

I've thought of two ways of implementing this:

1. Have a table with only ids (primary key, auto-increment) and do joins to a table that has all the item information.

   Advantages:

   - easy to understand
   - hard for someone that comes after me to get confused

   Disadvantages:

   - requires more debugging and coding since this system is already in use
   - seems weird to have a table with a single field
2. Have a single table using a sub-select to get the MAX value (+1) to apply to new items.

   Advantages:

   - single table
   - only minor code adjustments (but not all that different, maybe)

   Disadvantages:

   - prone to errors (manual increment, can't allow deletions or the MAX value might be off)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create a table called `item_ids` or something to generate id values.  It's okay that this has only a single column.

```
CREATE TABLE item_ids (
  item_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

You don't even need to commit any data to it.  You just use it to generate id values:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO item_ids DEFAULT VALUES;
SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
ROLLBACK;
```

So now you have a concurrency-safe method to create new id's.

Then you make a *compound primary key* for your `items` table.  You must use MyISAM for this.

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  item_id INT,
  seq_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  etc VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (item_id, seq_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

MyISAM supports an auto-increment column in a compound primary key, which will start over at value 1 for each new `item_id`.*  It also uses `MAX(item_id)+1` so if you delete the last one, its value will be reallocated.  This is unlike other use of AUTO_INCREMENT where a deleted value is not re-used.

Whether you insert a new item, or whether you insert a new copy of an existing item, you use a similar INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO items (item_id, name, etc) VALUES (@id, 'Stephane', 'etc');
```

The `@id` parameter is either a value of an existing item, or else the auto-generated value you got from the `item_ids` table.

* InnoDB supports auto-increment only as the first column of a primary or unique key, and it does not start over the count for each distinct value of the other column.