# adding next sequential number for primary key in append query

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I  need to create an  append query, that appends many records to a table. this table has a primary key, that is a sequential number.  How do I make my append  query, append records to the table and automatically assign the next sequential  number for the primary key? I woudl need to run this query on a live multi-user MYSQL server throughout the day
thanks!

Comment: Append to database? Append from database? Where does MySQL come in?

Comment: Hi Remou! I need to append to a MYSQL database table.

Comment: Appropriate tagging can lead to quicker and better answers.

Comment: Why is this tagged under ms-access? Is there something not mentioned in the question?

Comment: Are you looking for this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215698/mysql-manual-increment-ids

Check the answers!

Comment: As soon as you require a feature such as knowing what the next auto_increment is - you're doing something very, very wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the PK is a true auto-incremental field, you should be able to leave the PK out of your 'append' query.  The table will automatically assign the next value in sequence to your data row(s) that you are inserting.

ex: If you have this data in table `names`

```
id    name
1     Ken
2     Jon
3     Steve
```

And you run this query

`INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES ('Peter')`

Your table should automatically assign id # 4 to Peter

If the sequential PK is maintained manually, I would suggest you alter that field to be a true auto-incremental field if at all possible, or create a new auto-increment field and drop the old one.  Just make sure you update any other related tables before you drop the field.

Comment: my primary key field has an alphanumeric structure. It has a 2 letter prefix followed by a hypen and the sequential number. I am using MS Access to run the append query to my linked mysql database please advise.

Comment: How do you determine the 2 letter prefix? Is it always the same?